# Can queues be persistent

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

Documentation for MassTransit with RabbitMQ states:

[control queues are exclusive and auto-delete - they go away when you go away and are not shared.](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/configuration/transports/rabbitmq.html)

I'm unclear on the consequences here; in my system, I need queues to be durable, and messages to persist. If I need to bring down consumer processes (for updates, for example) or if I need to reboot the server (for Windows patching, say), I want existing queues to stick around and not lose any current messages, so processing can continue once everything is back in place, without dropping published messages. If no consumers are available, I want published messages to be able to accumulate until I get the consumer(s) back online.

In RabbitMQ, I can configure the queues to be durable and the messages to be persistent.  Is this possible if using MassTransit?

Or are "control queues" the queues that respond to control messages, unrelated to my app's queues?

Comment: To be clear: It's the auto-delete aspect that I'm concerned about, not the exclusive aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control queues are only for metadata, and not your application's data. You can safely ignore them. Your main data queues are durable by default.